# How to show in swimlane diagram sending some data to multiple clients

Tags: uml, flowchart, activity-diagram

I have a situation where one client is sending some data to server and then server is sending it to all the other clients.
Should I show the receiving at all the other clients in the same "Client" column in the swimlane diagram or should I make another column other than "Client" that says "Collection of Clients" or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about ADs: you have the choice to comment with a note like this:

[image]

For SDs sou can use multiplicity like that:

[image]

In that case the message is sent to multiple clients.

I seem to remember that some tools can show the client as stacked rectangles, but EA just shows it this way.